# Cannot read property 'save' of null error when using update mutaiton in GraphQL

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graphql

I am learning GraphQL and am developing a Contact Manager App using Node.js and my database is MongoDB. The add and delete mutation are working fine but whenever I try to run update mutation it throws error. I'm on Windows machine running on windows 10 20H2. Text editor is VS Code. Terminal is windows powershell and I'm using npm to run the program.

This is my `./graphql.js` file

```
    const express = require('express');
    const {contact_book} = require('../models/contact_book');
    const {User} = require('../models/user_registration');
    
    
    const typeDefs = `type Query {
        getContact(id: ID!): contact_book
        getContacts: [contact_book]
        getUser(id: ID!): User
        getUsers: [User]
      }
      type contact_book {
        id: ID!
        name: String!
        email: String
        phone: String!
      }
      type User {
        id: ID!
        name: String!
        password: String!
        email: String
        phone: String!
      }
      type Mutation {
        addUser(name: String!, password: String!, phone: String!, email: String!): User!,
        updateUser(id:ID!, name: String, password: String, phone: String, email: String):User,
        deleteUser(id: ID!): String,
        addContact(name: String!, phone: String!, email: String!): contact_book!,
        updateContact(id: ID!, name: String, phone: String, email: String):contact_book,
        deleteContact(id: ID!): String
        
      }`
    
    const resolvers = {
      Query: {
        getUsers: ()=> User.find(),
        getUser: async (_,{id}) => {
          const user = await User.findById(id);
          return ("User Created",user);
        },
        getContacts: ()=> contact_book.find(),
        getContact: async (_,{id}) => {
          const contact = await contact_book.findById(id);
          return contact;
        }
      },
      Mutation: {
        addUser: async (_, { name, password, email, phone }) => {
          const user = new User({name, password, email, phone});
          await user.save();
          return user;
        },
        updateUser: async(_, args)=>{
          const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate({id: args.id}, 
            { 
              name: args.name, 
              password: args.password,
              email: args.email, 
              phone: args.phone
            },{new: true});
          await user.save();
          return user; 
        },
        deleteUser: async (_, {id}) => {
          const user = await User.findByIdAndRemove(id);
          return ('User deleted');
        },
        addContact: async(_, { name, email, phone })=>{
          const contact = new contact_book({ name, email, phone });
          await contact.save();
          return contact
        },
        updateContact: async(_, args)=>{
          const contact = new contact_book.findOneAndUpdate({id: args.id},
            {
              name: args.name,
              email:args.email, 
              phone: args.email 
            },{new: true});
          await contact.save();
          return contact;
        },
        deleteContact: async(_, {id})=>{
          const contact = await contact_book.findByIdAndRemove(id);
          return ('Contact deleted');
        }
      }
    }
    
    module.exports = {typeDefs, resolvers,};
```

This is my `./index.js` file. Please ignore routes to REST API as I first implemented this code with REST.

```
const { GraphQLServer } = require('graphql-yoga');
const graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql').graphqlHTTP;
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const express = require('express');
const expressPlayground = require('graphql-playground-middleware-express').default;
const register = require('./routes/user_registration');
const login = require('./routes/user_login');
const contact = require('./routes/contact_book');
const {typeDefs, resolvers} = require('./graphql/graphql');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/ContactBook')
    .then(()=> console.log('Connected to db'))
    .catch(err=> console.log('Could not connect' ));

console.log('Running on port 4000');

/*const port = 4000;
app.listen(port, ()=>console.log(`Connected to port: ${port}`));*/

const server = new GraphQLServer({ typeDefs, resolvers })
mongoose.connection.once("open", function(){
    server.start(() => console.log('Server is running on localhost:4000'))
});

app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
    schema: typeDefs,
    rootValue: resolvers,
    graphiql: true,
  })
);
  

app.use('/api/register', register);
app.use('/api/login', login);
app.use('/api/contact_book', contact);
app.get('/', expressPlayground({ endpoint: '/graphql' }));
```

This is the error screenshot that I'm getting on GrapQL PLayground
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBhoR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look up the `User` document by `_id` and not `id`. And you don't need to call `save` since `findOneAndUpdate` already does the update.

```
const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: args.id },
  {
    name: args.name,
    password: args.password,
    email: args.email,
    phone: args.phone,
  },
  { new: true }
)
```

You could also use the [`Model.findByIdAndUpdate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) method.

```
const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
  args.id,
  {
    name: args.name,
    password: args.password,
    email: args.email,
    phone: args.phone,
  },
  { new: true }
)
```

You should do the same for `updateContact`. And there are a couple more issues. You shouldn't use the `new` keyword when calling `contact_book.findOneAndUpdate`. And you should pass `args.phone` to the `phone` key in the update document (your code passes `args.email`).

```js
const resolvers = {
  // ...
  updateUser: (_, args) =>
    User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: args.id },
      {
        name: args.name,
        password: args.password,
        email: args.email,
        phone: args.phone,
      },
      { new: true }
    ),
  updateContact: (_, args) =>
    contact_book.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: args.id },
      {
        name: args.name,
        email: args.email,
        phone: args.phone,
      },
      { new: true }
    ),
  // ...
}
```